# What's a free audio editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, audio

What's a free audio editor in it? It migth be made for Windows. It are needed for My Youtube video blog.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy!  If you need a gratis audio editor with specific functionality, please specify that functionality in your question.  Currently, this question is too broad.  There are dozens of good free audio editors for Windows.  Some of the open-source ones are listed here: https://www.fosshub.com/Audio-Editors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Audacity](https://www.audacity.de/). The tool is really powerfull when it comes to audio manipulation, you can work with multiple tracks, export to different audio formats...

The software is german, but as far as I know there are multiple languages available after the installation.